# laravel saving images start with comma

Tags: php, laravel

I have implemented dropzone js on my laravel project but af facing one issue on saving the images on the database

,/uploads/products/27/607f0fc0942b0_1618939840_fc3cde370d846c4d14b0200a29e9206f.png,/uploads/products/27/607f0fc0945e8_1618939840_copy-space-with-opened-quran_23-2148214357.jpg,/uploads/products/27/607f0fc09474d_1618939840_1 (1).jpg

the issue is the images start with a comma which is wrong and it must be after the image for example
image1.png,image2.png

**Here is my Controller**

```
            $product_images = json_decode($request->product_images[0],true);
            $images = [];
            $path = "";
            
            $productsPath = 'uploads/products/';
            $productPath = 'uploads/products/'.$request->product_id;
            if(!file_exists($productsPath)){
                mkdir($productsPath);
            } 
            
            
            if (!file_exists($productPath)) {
                mkdir($productPath, 0777,true);
            }
            foreach($product_images as $img){    
                
                $file = $img['name'];
                // $extension = $img->guessExtension();
                $filename = uniqid() .'_'. time() .'_'. $file;
                
                $img = explode(',',$img['file'])[1];

                $img = str_replace('', '+', $img);
                $data = base64_decode($img);

                $file = $productPath .'/'. $filename;
                $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
            //  dd($file);
                $images[] = '/'. $file;
            }


            // Update Product Information On "products" table
            $product = Product::where('id', $request->product_id)->first();
            $product->created_by = auth()->user()->id;
            $product->name = request('name_en');
            $product->name_ar = request('name_ar');
            $product->description = request('description_en'); // Must be moved to "product_information"
            $product->description_ar = request('description_ar'); // Must be moved to "product_information"
            $product->youtube = request('youtube'); // Must be moved to "product_information"
            $product->youtube_ar = request('youtube_ar'); // Must be moved to "product_information"
            $product->slug = slugify($request->name_en, 'Product', '', '');
            // $product->image = request('name_en');
            $product->brand_id = request('brand');
            $product->status = request('status');
            $data = explode(',' ,$product->image);
            
            $data = array_merge($data,$images);
            
            $remove_images = json_decode($request->removed_images, true);
            $temp = [];
            $i = 0;
            foreach($data as $key => $imag){
                $i  = $i + 1;
                if(!empty($remove_images) && in_array($imag, $remove_images)){
                    if (file_exists($productPath .'/'. $imag)) {
                        unlink($productPath .'/'. $imag);
                    }
                }else{
                    if($i < 8)
                        $temp[] = $imag;
                }
            }
            $product->image = implode($temp, ',');
            // dd (explode(',' ,$product->image));
            
            $product->save();
```

thank you

Comment: Have you done any debugging to determine the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

use implode like this

```
implode(',', $temp);
```